# Finding usage of jQuery UI in a big ugly codebase

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've recently inherited the maintenance of a big, ugly codebase for a production website.
Poke your eyes out ugly. And though it's big, it's mostly PHP code, it doesn't have much JS, besides a few "ajaxy" things in the UI.

Our main current problem is that the site is just too heavy. Homepage weighs in at 1.6 Mb currently, so I'm trying to clean some stuff out.

One of the main wasters is that every single page includes the jQuery UI library, but I don't think it's used at all. It's definitely not being used in the homepage and in most pages, so I want to only include the  where necessary.

I'm not really experienced with jQuery, i'm more of a Prototype guy, so I'm wondering. Is there anything I could search for that'd let me know where jQuery UI is being used?
What i'm looking for is "common strings", component names, etc

For example, if this was scriptaculous, i'd look for things like "Draggable", "Effect", etc.
Any suggestions for jQuery UI?

(Of course, if you can think of a more robust way of removing the  tag from pages that don't use it without breaking everything, I'd love to hear about it)

Thanks!! 
Daniel

Comment: If you're sending the appropriate cache headers, or using a CDN (e.g. Google's, which does the cache headers appropriately), then the client's not downloading this every page load.  Is that not the case?  If it isn't, you have a separate issue that should be addressed, re-downloading static content isn't good.

Comment: I'm addressing that too, Nick, but the first hit to the homepage is still getting taxed unnecessary, and we're also getting big bandwidth problems because of this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

jQuery UI has a standard naming convention, [you can view a full list of widgets/effects here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI).  Comparing to that list you're looking for the corresponding methods mostly:

- [`.draggable()`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable)
- [`.droppable()`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable)
- [`.dialog()`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)
- etc...

**However**, and this is a big however, if your main goal is to reduce page payload size, this *should* **have no effect**.  Your users shouldn't be downloading this every page load, [it should be cached on the client as determined by cache headers](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html), additionally [your scripts should be minified (already provided version when you download it) and delivered gzipped](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html).

Also if it's an option, I'd consider [using a CDN for both jQuery and jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746075/whats-faster-for-including-scripts-using-cdn-google-or-store-them-locally-in-w), and [the stylesheets as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820412/jquery-css-download-from-google), if you're using one of the default themes.

Comment: Nick, thanks for your answer. My main problem right now is that the first time you hit the website, you get a 188kb file (it's minified already, not gzipped, i'm working on that too). As for Google's AJAX hosting, i've tried that too, but this is a server in Argentina for an Argentinean audience. Believe it or not (I barely can), the JS files loads faster from our server than Google's, when we're not overloaded. I will probably still move it to the bottom and ask for it from Google, but if I can remove it altogether, it's much better. Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel - Something to keep in mind is that google's geographically balanced as well, you need to test from a computer in the region rather than remotely, as you're loading from a different CDN node.  As more people link to google's CDN, there's also a chance the user *already* cached the file :)

Comment: I'm testing from Argentina :-) I also know about the "people can have it cached already" effect, but I'm not really sure how much that has happened already. Do you have any figures as to how widespread this use is? That said, I'd still prefer to eliminate a useless (and heavy) file even if it's coming from someone else's fast server.

Comment: Right, I did something along these lines using egrep (or grep -E) so I could use regular expressions to match common jquery-ui strings:

    `egrep -r "\.draggable\(|\.droppable\(|\.resizable\(|\.selectable\(|\.sortable\(|\.accordion\(|\.autocomplete\(|\.button\(|\.datepicker\(|\.dialog\(|\.menu\(|\.progressbar\(|\.slider\(|\.tabs\(|\.tooltip\(|\$\.widget\(" src/`

This can give some false-positives, but should get you most of the way there.

Answer (score 6):

See this article: https://medium.com/software-developer/finding-jquery-ui-usage-in-a-project-b4fbcfc938c8

It is used for generate big ugly regexp.

I use it as base and got next regexp:

`\.\s*(accordion|autocomplete|button|buttonset|datepicker|dialog|menu|progressbar|selectmenu|slider|spinner|tabs|tooltip|effect|switchClass|switchClass|draggable|droppable|mouse|resizable|selectable|sortable|disableSelection|enableSelection|removeUniqueId|scrollParent|uniqueId|zIndex)\s*\(|['"](blind|bounce|clip|drop|explode|fade|fold|highlight|puff|scale|shake|size|slide|transfer|easeInQuad|easeOutQuad|easeInOutQuad|easeInCubic|easeOutCubic|easeInOutCubic|easeInQuart|easeOutQuart|easeInOutQuart|easeInQuint|easeOutQuint|easeInOutQuint|easeInExpo|easeOutExpo|easeInOutExpo|easeInSine|easeOutSine|easeInOutSine|easeInCirc|easeOutCirc|easeInOutCirc|easeInElastic|easeOutElastic|easeInOutElastic|easeInBack|easeOutBack|easeInOutBack|easeInBounce|easeOutBounce|easeInOutBounce)['"]|:(data|focusable|tabbable)|\.ui\b`

Here can be a lot false positives, but I think it is good start. In any case you need manually check all matches.

Comment: How to use this regex in grep command ? grep followed by the regex?

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be to look at the jQuery UI demo page - http://jqueryui.com/demos/ - and look at each demo and search for the main one or two keywords from each demo, like you would probably do for Scriptaculous.  Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest doing a search for `$(document).ready` or trying to figure out the equivalent the codebase uses to check if the DOM is ready for jquery interaction. Because the UI additions require the DOM all the calls for them are going to be within those functions - you can see where they occur and you can check in them for any of common [interactions or widgets](http://jqueryui.com/demos/)

Comment: A site may have no references to `$(document).ready`, or `jQuery(document)`, or `something(document)`, or `$(function() {` with no `document`, etc...there are many shortcuts, none of which are jQuery UI specific.  He wants to remove jQuery UI, not jQuery :)

Answer (score -3):

The library really should account for only 19k of the page size.

But you could search for $(' or $. as most, if not all, jquery calls begin with $.

Comment: or search for jQuery( if the codebase uses that instead of $(' to avoid any possible naming conflicts.

Comment: @Chad, not sure that's what was asked.  I think he wants to find where jQuery was being used.  if the lib is included at the master page level then you'll only find "jQuery" there.  need to search for specific references and $ is a fairly good one.

Comment: @griegs - I don't think you guys read the question :) He wants to remove **jQuery UI**, not jQuery core.

Comment: @Nick, yeah fair call.  Still there must be some common theme to calling a jQuery UI method.

Comment: @griegs -There's a convention, I just added a more complete answer for this...but I don't think it's the appropriate way to address the OPs speed issue anyway, tried to include some other tips around that.

Comment: +1 @Nick.  I think your right.  I suspect that jQuery UI might not be the issue.  w/out seeing the site i'd be looking at images as a likely factor in the page size. then i'd look at the javascript.

Comment: @griegs - take a look at the jQuery.noConflict call.  Since he has a "big, ugly codebase" I thought that there might be multiple JS libraries and that might mean that whoever coded it originally used the noConflict option.  If that is the case, he'll want to search for jQuery( instead of $(

In any case, I did - accidentally - ignore that he was asking about the UI library.

Comment: @griegs: Images account for 1Mb. Now they've been severely recompressed and that went down a lot. Scripts account for 600kb. That is ridiculous to me, so I'm working on that too.