# What is the best way to include latest version of jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm developing sites using Wordpress and I want to use the lates version of jQuery.

To make sure I use the lates version, I have found this piece of code from [Binary Bonsai's example](http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/force-wordpress-use-latest-version-jquery/).

What I see, is that he actually links to jQuery at Google API.

So my question is, what is better.

To link to jQuery on an external page?
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

or to have the jquery file locally?
`wp_enqueue_script('jquery', '/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js');`

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Colin, the answer is actually here:
[Why should I use Google's CDN for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery)

But tjust in case you don't have `Google` in your search term, like me, I'll copy the answer from  John Gietzen

1. **It increases the parallelism available.**
   (Most browsers will only download 3 or 4 files at a time from any given site)
2. **It increases the chance that there will be a cache-hit.**
   (As more sites follow this practice, more users have the file already ready.)
3. **It ensures that the payload will be as small as possible.**
   (Google can pre-gzip-compress the file, making the time-to-download very small.)
4. **It reduces the amount of bandwidth used by the server.**
   (Google is basically offering free bandwidth.)
5. **It ensures that the user will get a geographically close response.**
   (Google has servers all over the world, further decreasing the latency.)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery

Comment: ah, didn't find them when I search (didn't search for google).

Comment: Now that you said it, using Google as jQuery hoster really has loads of advantages. Will immediately change my code to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can leave out the minor or dot versions when linking to the google CDN copies, like this:

- jQuery 1.4.2: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
- Latest 1.4.x: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js
- Latest 1.x.x: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

Given this flexibility, I much prefer the remote version, it's quick to get bug fixes by just changing the URL and the file's loaded faster (in *most* cases) because it's pulled from another domain (and not in the count of parallel requests to your domain).  There are other related questions on this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180391/why-should-i-use-googles-cdn-for-jquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746075/whats-faster-for-including-scripts-using-cdn-google-or-store-them-locally-in-w).

Comment: I think it's "dangerous" to use 1.4.x or 1.x.x, because if if changes are made to jQuery which e.g. Wordpress has yet not implemented (or I not updated custom plugins), then Wordpress (or my plugin) may break  - all of th sudden. So I would say the safest way would be to use 1.4.2, and later manually update to 1.4.3 whne I have tsted that this works.

Comment: @Steven - I agree, and this is how I use it, the full `1.4.2` in the URL (the same scheme works with jQuery UI by the way, on it's CSS as well).  However, *if* you want the latest of whatever version, you have the *option*, which is a nice feature IMO, the way they leave it up to the developer to choose.

Answer (score 6):

That would not get you the latest version.  That would get you 1.4.2 every time.

This would, though:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
```

Though, I would prefer local, and lock the version at the point where I developed it and verified it was working...

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds. Just looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441412/is-there-a-link-to-the-latest-jquery-library-on-google-apis

Comment: My question though, was not how to have the latest version, but what is better; To have it lcoally or link to google :-)

Comment: You may want to caveat this, as soon as 1.4.3 is release this answer won't make a lot of sense :)

Comment: I don't think Google will remove old versions, just add new ones. So when the time comes to upgrade to 1.4.3, I must update my plugin code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there are pros and cons of each, but I personally prefer to have the file locally.  My reason for this is that it is possible that at sometime in the future a feature might get deprecated, and if you happen to use that feature in your now stable and long unmodified script, then it may break your code.

Comment: Then I assume you ship a specific browser in a specific version with your site as well, because the odds of any browser changing in a breaking way seems about a thousand times lower than jQuery changing in a breaking way. :)

Comment: Oh, that's a very idiosyncratic view of programming. That means you don't maintain the pages, and there's a big movement in web standards in particular.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick Craver mentioned in his answer, you can leave out the major/minor versions from the URLs for the google CDN.

The main benefits of using a CDN for these sorts of files though is the performance benefit and the saving in bandwidth.

Any recent browser will use a cached copy of files which have been accessed before, and as this (along with many others) is used on thousands (millions?) of sites across the net, it's very likely that users visiting your site will already have this file cached.

So it saves the users bandwidth, as well as your own. And that's never a bad thing.

Also, if there is a new version of the jQuery framework available, even if you hosted it locally, you'd still have to update the local copy, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

1) Local file

```
<script src="js/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or, if you use Wordpress:
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', '/js/jquery-latest.min.js');

You have to download the latest when a new version comes out, and rename it to jquery-latest.min.js. If is the easiest if you hardcode the file reference on many pages.

2) from Google CDN

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.load('jquery', '1.4.2');
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You have to update the version number to the latest when a new version comes out. Easier than method one if you have a template that allows you to update a single place to reflect the change on every page.

3) from jQuery’s server

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
```

Easy as it is always the latest. However, it may not be as reliable and fast as Google's CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the external jquery.js file is version 1.4.2 and that wouldn't change if jQuery were updated. Would you really want the jQuery codebase to update without you knowing? If your code is working, why risk breaking it by letting the jQuery version update automatically?