# Minify & Gzip vs Google CDN

Tags: jquery, performance, gzip, cdn, minify

Should I minify/gzip my Jquery with my other scripts on my page, or use Google CDN for Jquery & JQuery UI and gzip my own stuff.

From what I can see its more likely to be faster to deliver from Google and there is a better chance the files will be cached already on the users machine, however its a couple of extra http request and at least I know it will always be available.

Comment: related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746075/whats-faster-for-including-scripts-using-cdn-google-or-store-them-locally-in-w

Comment: http://cachedcommons.org/ is also offering a couple of files on github cdn

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to **measure** on your site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it right.
For widely-used librairies, using Google CDN is a good idea:

- uses less bandwith on your server
- resources availability is great
- servers location is good too (it's a CDN after all!)
- like you said, better chances these resources will be cached already on the user's side

The only downside:

- adds a DNS query, because you're hosting resources on an additional domain. [Reducing DNS lookups is quite important](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#dns_lookups).

So the anwser is "use Google CDN".