# "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'html':

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to pop up a message if session times out and some error message comes back from my controller.

My include is as follows....

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/jqueryui/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css") %>"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/slideshow.css") %>"/>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/jquery-1.6.2.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.js") %>"></script>
```

Here is the code:

```
<% 
        string AlertMessage2 = TempData["PublicAlertMessage"] as string;
        string AlertMessage2Title = TempData["AlertMessageTitle"] == null ? String.Empty : TempData["AlertMessageTitle"] as string;

        if( AlertMessage2 != null )
        { %>
          <div id="AlertMessage" title="">

             </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             jQuery.noConflict();
                 $("#AlertMessage").html("<center><%= AlertMessage2 %></center>");
                 $("#AlertMessage").dialog({ height: 240, width: 350, modal: true, title: '<%= AlertMessage2Title %>', buttons: { "OK": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } } });

             });
          </script>

      <% } %>
```

I am getting "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'html': object is null or undefined" when I implement the following Jquery dialog.

Am I missing any include file? I have no clue and where to look! any ideas?

Thanks!

Now I can see the modal window... but getting error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'" in ok button

This is in IE 9. When I try in Google chrome, I cannot close the modal window.

```
$("#AlertMessage").dialog({
                     height: 200,
                     width: 250,
                     modal: true,
                     title: '<%= AlertMessage2Title %>',
                     buttons: { "OK": function () { 
                    // $(this).dialog('close'); --> comment this and try to run... no issues
                     } } });
```

what's wrong with the buttons?

Update on 29th: If I remove the close functionality of ok, there is no error. But how do I close the modal window? any other work around?

Update on Dec 2nd:
This code does not work in IE 8 and IE 9. Also the pop up window does not close. But no problem in IE 7.

Comment: Why are you including jQuery UI as eight separate JavaScript files instead of just one?

Comment: Also: `<center>` tags are sooo 1997.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss a dependency used by jQuery Ui dialog:

```
UI Core
**UI Position**
UI Widget
UI Mouse (Optional; only needed if using UI Draggable or UI Resizable)
UI Draggable (Optional)
UI Resizable (Optional)
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

If you want to include the entire jQuery UI suite you can make a unique file and include it.

Comment: Yes, I read that the main dependencies are core, position and widget. I added and ran the code. Still I get the same error!

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use, 1.6.2? Can you try with 1.7? And what del of jQuery UI? Here is a "fast" working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Version 1.6.2.  I googled about this error. Somebody commented that it required some kind of order to include js files. Now I see the model window, but still error is coming up on .dialog of the OK button! Jquery Ui 1.8.16.custom.js

Comment: Can you try with a complete 1.8.6 custom? No splitted UI js files

Comment: I prefer use chat, but you can't join. So try use jQuery 1.7 please?

Comment: same... Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'. This .dialog  on Button function.

Comment: Is the url content correct? Can you post the resultant html page code?

Comment: Url content is correct. As I am appending with '~' it recognizes and gets the right file. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xxx/Content/jqueryui/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xxx/css/slideshow.css"/>   
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/xxx/js/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/xxx/Scripts/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.js"></script> Sorry, I cannot post the entire html code here. :(

Comment: To check the problem, have you tried to use: $('#AlertMessage').dialog.('close'); ?

Comment: Hve you got Telerik controls? Can this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845552/jquery-dialog-problem ?

Comment: I do have telerik controls in my app. but not on this view. It's the home page and I am trying to show my session time out message with ok button. That's it. Some images with login fields that's it. But anyway I tried to register as a group for my telerik. Still it's not working

Comment: mmm, interesting...some test! Have you got prototype or other js framework called (es. prototype) or get a script can override $; can you try using jQuery(this).dialog('close') instead of $(this).dialog('close')? You can you check out this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ too ?

Comment: Yes.. .I tried ( jQuery(this).dialog("close");) still I get the error... :(

Comment: mmm, can you try using jquery.noconflict() please?