# How to use jquery and javascript efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery and its related plugins in my site.

Since i use more js. for visiting each page in my site. all the js loads so site loading time increases.

**How to use js libraries efficiently without loading js for each page visit.**

**UPDATE:**

I am using

```
        <!-- JQUERY-->
        <script src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $.noConflict();
        </script>
        <script src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- JQUERY.VALIDATE SCRIPT -->
        <script src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!--JS VALIDATION SCRIPTS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/scriptaculous/lib/prototype.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/scriptaculous/src/scriptaculous.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/jsvalidate.js"></script>

        <!--jQuery URL Script-->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/jquery.url.js"></script>


        <!-- TINYMCE SCRIPTS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
        <script src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/tinymce/tiny_mce_src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/quicktags.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- WORD COUNT -->
        <script src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/jquery.wordcount.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Thick box scripts -->
        <script src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/thickbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<!--JS FOR GRAPH (Highcharts Refer: http://highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-pie-point-events)-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/graph/highcharts.js"></script>

        <!-- 1a) Optional: add a theme file -->
        <!--
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/graph/themes/gray.js"></script>
        -->

        <!-- 1b) Optional: the exporting module -->
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/graph/modules/exporting.js"></script>-->


        <!--JS FOR Tag adding in Faq add1.html - added by Mogan Dec 02, 2010-->
        <script src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/create_html.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--FANCY BOX -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$TEMPLATE_FACK}/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

**This much of js i am using in header section. once i am visiting each page all these loads again and again**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user doesn't have to load it each time, just be sure to [set your cache headers correctly](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html) so the user caches the JavaScript files that are reused.  For libraries specifically (since this is tagged jQuery), [look at using a CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746075/whats-faster-for-including-scripts-using-cdn-google-or-store-them-locally-in-w/2746108#2746108) - which will also have the cache headers I mention, as well as parallelizing the download since it's not on your own domain.

Comment: for me each time js loads. i had checked it with fire bug. For every page all of my js loads

Comment: @Mohan - Then one of two things is going on...your cache headers *aren't* set correctly, as I mention above....*or* on the **Net** panel in Firebug, the dropdown from the tab itself, there's a **Disable Browser Cache** option which you have checked.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can use a [Content delivery network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (CDN) for libraries like jQuery etc. Google provides [a bunch](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html).

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the previous answer you should minify all javascript file together, optionally you can use gzip compression.