# How can I use “Little Loader” to load js files with dependencies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, loader

I am trying to speed up the loading of DataTables.js. Currently the websites UI is available for almost 4 seconds before the DataTables' features appear. One idea I had was to use a JavasScript loader. I did some research and found little-loader.js. The examples do not mention how to use it to load files with dependencies. How can I use it to load such files? Here is my code so far:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/little-loader@VERSION/dist/little-loader.min.js"></script>

<script>
window._lload("http://example.com/jquery-min.js", function (err) {
   // `err` is script load error.
   if( err === '' ) {
       window._lload("http://example.com/js/datatables-min.js", function (err) {
       //Maybe load other scripts
       } );
   }

} );
</script>
```

Comment: How are you populating the datatable? I'm fairly confident that the loading issue could be solved without resorting to another plugin.

Comment: I am using an already constructed html table.  No data is loaded.

Comment: i believe you have to use json data instead of constructing it in html, it should be able to load faster

Comment: load faster for development or for deployment?

If for local development just require locally,
for deployment,

make sure you follow best practices :) 
https://betterexplained.com/articles/speed-up-your-javascript-load-time/

you could try caching it in local storage
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746075/whats-faster-for-including-scripts-using-cdn-google-or-storing-them-locally